# Confusion in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named 'TA' and I am confused about why the two following queries give me different results:

```
select * 
from (
select name, date, country, age
from TA
where date = '2019-08-08' and teacher = 'AA'
group by date, name, country, age
) c
where c.country = 'US' and c.name = 'TOM'
```

```
select * 
from (
select name, date, country, age
from TA
where date = '2019-08-08' and teacher = 'AA'
group by date, name, country, age
) c
where c.country= 'US'
```

In the second table if I filter the name and look at 'TOM' results it is totally different!!

Comment: What are the differences between the results? The first query just has an additional condition compared to the first one.

Comment: So, for instance, I get 5 rows for the first one and 3 rows corresponding to 'TOM' in the second one.

Comment: @user3554121 ... You probably just need to sort the results of the first query by name so you see all the `'Tom'`s together.

Comment: Yeah! but this is a small part of a big query and of course a simple example of that.

Comment: Can you show us the result set? How are they different?